# Sign In with Apple (on a website) returns an empty user object

Tags: apple-sign-in

I have implemented Sign In with Apple on my website. But the problem is that it only works with my developer's Apple ID.

I tried to use my personal Apple ID from the same environment, and the sign in process also did run fine.

However, when real users are trying to use this feature, Apple returns the wrong response with an empty JSON for `user` field, like this:

```
{  
  "state": "20cadefd",  
  "code": "c0f4d18d62a124c9482dec72e9b647f6d.0.nwus.L-JUin6NT_fZPDn4B8oYaA",  
  "user" => "{}"  
}
```

As you can see, the user object is empty.

Querying `https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token` gives back no email claim as well. It is also reported that users do not see the usual step where one can share or hide his real email.

What am I missing here?

*** UPDATE ***

As for the `id_token`, I can get it and decode, it gives the following:

```
{
  "iss": "https://appleid.apple.com",
  "aud": "<SERVICE ID>",
  "exp": 1578056278,
  "iat": 1578055678,
  "sub": "<SUB ID>",
  "at_hash": "rFEqY8BcGQVfxwFxgAsWsA",
  "auth_time": 1578055675
}
```

Still no email field

*** UPDATE ***

With further tests it seems that the "user" field is only empty when the user signs in with his Touch ID. When he uses the password, it's all fine.

Comment: This is how it works. It provides only email from token request and only once. You need to decode `id_token` from token request response and you'll get `sub` and `email` claims from it.

Comment: You need to use jwt library to decode `id_token`

Comment: What I provided in the question *is* the first request response. Subsequent requests' responses lack `user` field and I'm aware of that. The problem is that the first response gives an empty object.

As for the `id_token`, I can get it and decode, I've updated the question with the contents.

Comment: I posted a question about this problem to Apple Developer forums and Apple tech support, still no answer.

Comment: It turns out that the "user" field is only empty when the user signs in with his Touch ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing a quite similar issue while implementing Sign In with Apple on a website and I've come to a solution that worked for me.

Everything worked fine when I was signing in on a desktop browser but when I was signing in on mobile and using touch ID, Apple returned an empty JSON for user field even on the first request - even if I made sure to remove my website from the authorised apps in my appleid account.

There was an issue with the way multiple `scope` attributes were encoded in the URL: `name+email` doesn't work, but `name%20email` does.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's very weird.